# Nonnegative integer solutions and strictly positive solutions to linear equation

Tags: combinatorics

I'm working with some combinatorics and have met a problem of the following form:

Calculate the number of non negative integer solutions to $\sum_{i=1}^r x_i = n$. Of course, assuming that $n$ is also a non negative integer and $r \leq n$.

I'm pretty comfortable solving these problems when thinking visually in terms of placing out $r-1$ separators corresponding to each "addition" somewhere between $n$ balls, giving me the fact that the amount of non negative integer solutions is $$\begin{pmatrix}
n - r + 1 \\ r - 1
\end{pmatrix}$$

However, if we constrain ourselves to only strictly positive integers, meaning we don't include the $0$. I became stuck in solving problems of this sort. I understand that we somehow have to get at least $1$ ball between our separators. But how do you show what the result becomes mathematically?

Thank you for any help.

Comment: In your title, you wrote non integer solutions when you meant nonnegative integer solutions.  I have corrected the error.

Answer (score 1):

Note that the number of positive integer solutions of
$$\sum_{i=1}^{r} x_i = n$$
is the same as the number of non-negative integer solutions of
$$\sum_{i=1}^r (x_i+1) = n$$
and after transformation:
$$\sum_{i=1}^r x_i = n-r$$
By transforming the respective terms, you can use your formula to count the number of positive solutions.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use separators to solve the problem
$$x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + \cdots + x_r = n$$
in the positive integers.  A particular solution of the equation corresponds to the placement of $r - 1$ separators in the $n - 1$ spaces between successive balls in a row of $n$ identical balls.
$$b \square b \square b \square \cdots \square b \square b \square b$$
Notice that there must be at least one ball between any two separators.  The number of such solutions is the number of ways we can select $r - 1$ of the $n - 1$ spaces between successive balls in which to place a separator, which is $$\binom{n - 1}{r - 1}$$